# Bottle Python ping check 5 pings

Tags: python, bottle

I am trying to write a script to print a ping check to the browser with 5 pings.

This script:

```
from bottle import route, run, template
import subprocess

@route('/pings/<ip>')

def ping(ip):
   param = '-c 1'
   command = ['ping', param, ip]
   num = 0
   while (num < 6):
      return subprocess.check_output(command)
      num += 1

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Currently outputs to the browser as follows:

> PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8:
>   icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=17.7 ms --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 1
>   packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt
>   min/avg/max/mdev = 17.756/17.756/17.756/0.000 ms

But it doesn't print out 5 pings like I expect it to. It only prints out the one ping, is it for some reason only printing out the last one? How can I print out 5 pings like it would look if you ran it from a shell command.

Thanks.

Comment: `return` ends the function, so you only run `subprocess.check_output` once.  You'll have to run it multiple times, collect the results in a container like a list, and then return that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is only running once because `return` is executed during the first iteration of the loop therefore you're only getting the first result. You can get the ping result and append that to a list then once the loop is complete you can just return that list.

```
def ping(ip):
   param = '-c 1'
   command = ['ping', param, ip]
   num = 0
   output = []
   while (num < 6):
      output.append(subprocess.check_output(command))
      num += 1
   return output // or return "\n".join(output)
```

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str' - Googling it now

Comment: Sorry made a typo! Fixed it now

Comment: I picked up on that, thanks. I actually could change param = 'c 1' to param = 'c 6' as well it turns out, but I prefer to loop so I can add new lines after each ping